# ActiveRecord query to avoid needing of additional processing of the results

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models: Employment and Email. Employment has_many :emails and Email belongs_to :employment.

I need to find employments that have no working emails.

This means I need to find employments with associated emails where deactivated_on is not nil and also have no associated emails where deactivated_on is nil. (deactivated_on is a date)

I could find all of the employments with emails where deactivated_on is nil and then iterate through each employment's emails in ruby to return only the employments with no emails where deactivated_on is nil. But I expect there must be a way to write a query that achieves this result.

I am open to ActiveRecord or raw sql if necessary.

I currently have:

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails

  def no_working_emails
    joins(:emails).where.not(emails: { deactivated_on: nil }).uniq
  end
end
```

This results in employment objects associated with emails where deactivated_on is nil and also emails where deactivated_on is not nil.

I need to remove the employments that also have emails where deactivated_on is not nil.

I have been researching [group](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group) with [having](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-having) or a subquery using from. But so far I can't shake off those employments with active email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query similar to the following should help you get at the IDs of all employments that have *no* active emails.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all <<-SQL
  select e.id
  from employments e
  where not exists (
    select 1
    from emails em
    where em.employment_id=e.id
      and em.deactivated_on = null
  );
SQL
```